# Display Random String in Org-Mode?

Tags: org-mode

I'm looking into figuring out if it would be possible to display a random quote on the top of my agenda that changes daily or whenever I check out the `agenda`.

I have a Quotes.org file that I capture to with `** QUOTE` items.

Would anything like this be possible?

EDIT: Works with the following code.

```
(defun read-lines (filePath)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents filePath)
    (split-string (buffer-string) "\n" t)))
(setq number-quotes (length (read-lines "~/Documents/emacs/myFile.org")))
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("c" "Daily Quote & Agenda & TODOs"
         ((insert (nth (random number-quotes) (read-lines "~/Documents/emacs/myFile.org")))
          (agenda "" nil)
          (alltodo "" nil)
                  nil))))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a custom agenda command in `org-agenda-custom-commands`, and add a special function to it.  The function should take one argument, a match string (which defaults to the empty string).  It can insert whatever text it wants to with `insert`.

For example, I tried this custom command:

```el
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("n" "Agenda and all TODO's"
         ((my-agenda-spook "" nil)
          (agenda "" nil)
          (alltodo "" nil)
        nil))
```

And defined `my-agenda-spook` like this, ignoring the match argument:

```el
(defun my-agenda-spook (&rest _ignore)
  (spook))
```

Then this appeared at the top of my agenda:

```
Taiwan Security Council First responder FMS white noise Drug war
analyzer arrangements beanpole bluebird PSAC Afghanistan gorilla ASLET
Basque Separatists

======================================================================================================================================
Week-agenda (W42):
Monday     12 October 2015 W42
...

======================================================================================================================================
Global list of TODO items of type: ALL
...
```

(`spook` is an ancient Emacs command that aims to feed NSA's keyword scanner.  I just chose it as an example of a function that inserts random strings; you might want to choose a different command for your agenda view.)

Comment: I cannot seem to make this work. I've tried replacing the spook argument with something very simple like `(nth 0 '("one"))` but it just doesn't want to work. Am I returning the wrong type of value?

Comment: The function needs to insert the string into the buffer, so that should be `(insert (nth 0 ...))`.

Comment: Oh man, it works! Thank you! I was tearing my hair out over that one.